# Как вывести ссылку генерируемую google-authenticator на CentOs сервере, в Web-сервер

Tags: python, rest

Развернуты два сервера на CentOs, сейчас первый сервер при авторизации по ssh генерирует google-authenticator, на втором развернута авторизационная форма, которая при вводе логина и пароля должна обращаться к серверу с google-authenticator и показывать генерируемый QR Code.
Как организовать передачу авторизационных данных пользователя на сервер c google-authenticator, и передавать генерируемую ссылку с QR кодом

Comment: последний раз делал - qrcode вышел в консоли. сфоткал и пользуюсь

Comment: Это понятно. Для одного пользователя это сделать просто, а десятку пользователей нужно уже будет стучаться сервер и сами генерить QR code. Для этого и хочу внедрить веб-форму, которая будет отправлять запрос на сервер с аутентификатором. Но вот как связать их?

Comment: зачем вам на сервере десяток пользователей? оО